# twitter bootstrap images grid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap and I would like to create a grid that will shrink according to the width of the screen and move it cells down. Right now I managed to create a grid like this: http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/3179/.

The problem is that the grid is not aligned very well and if I shrink the window the images are getting smaller instead of moving to the next row.

Is there any well knows practice to do that?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
            <div id="search" class="well form-search search">
                <input id="search-term" type="text" placeholder="Type search term">
                <button id="search-button" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div id="grid" class="span9">
            <div class="span3">
                <img class="img-polaroid" src="http://lh5.googleusercontent.com/public/zSxr-JuTje4AqFmN8zOFNcRaRm7L_QxmCaqzYSdnzHfKSHCIeM9G5NHKsdNy8BwnMLwhYHI4h_G6gNXA3c_3Zc8ggsXtPeG-fhk_IALFoH0b1HPrdxsBIszYLsUye_lvyffBsdxn_hfF9Ktng7BAgWjT56mDYBqpZXX25BC-odQ2mn8O" alt=""/>
            </div>
            <div class="span3">
                <img class="img-polaroid" src="http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/public/tN2kf46FC7y_IEd2vzJz9v4PhVsMFjV4scZovvLYRVTMk8OdYRBBlM1l263Nuak7rQVQHT107NfwWsZQ-9_MFoiOXKozErla4banQF51QyT5igHT-QKo6cRmUiTvVbQVkjgRYIh8sPutpY-XTrG8nEludMnt6GTuOg" alt=""/>
            </div>
            <div class="span3">
                <img class="img-polaroid" src="http://lh6.googleusercontent.com/public/AF-Zvxnq21ZQFZNwC4_XQnwN9-sudTFlohx7d7llv11R_60jpmPNhW679uLMzcShWd73vNAHhuTYZHFJF3rsCh7EVczcRnm-cd6KcrLDJEWWceyBUePnOPDerPf_5sovWzACyipV4JMf4k9-HomEbOwYIrwa0SwoBDXc1mwhSxVWreCs8DLNpeMRx-o" alt=""/>
            </div>
            <div class="span3">
                <img class="img-polaroid" src="http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/public/IYgOn9vXVD4zHB1d67KpX9--z0NDR0URCxEPTA32KFWTSDn9l2f7XR3tt0TTRAekThgUOCH0f0dGJn5ZLh3dUAXh1IDDrlbFJNmxGeVZt_eTTIG4YB23pXSfDH1Cx5OhNoEiaCCz4QAr-e8c" alt=""/>
            </div>
            <div class="span3">
                <img class="img-polaroid" src="http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/public/QDiY5hfLbDwEbvJmAgrcX4vRURGFEMBO6V66-EW_4YJGW5xJNCSLwwCltUB0YT1f0QMkUeztQZaI07KcsnxqEaaByAIq-ihvwPxg4B6wJuhEDjBIh1Bu5Txz0NBijb9y1dRdnSbtPImzk2HoSAcHUqfphDJwE1gfmErGtT0Apw" alt=""/>
            </div>

            <div class="span3">
                <img class="img-polaroid" src="http://lh6.googleusercontent.com/public/jIGAV-2KIt3YoKQ7zDtJN44qj6puwAk5J_GVCJCRnTTOB_idlMB-cyI9d0KTy-FL965GcOJbBeH1C8ros9FMhGxQW6ZToyr-qOYYx18FomndcKpC8TxsJAMpaz9IsT48WGfe_OgsKf9heJoEGhHGTw" alt=""/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="term-history" class="span3">
            <h2>Search history:</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);">camera</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `container-fluid` and `row-fluid` classes to `container` and `row`. Then include the bootstrap-responsive.css file. Work from there. Fluid and responsive is not the same thing, although they're related and often used together. Fluid layouts adjust their **widths** when resized, which seems to be not what you want. Responsive layouts generally adjust their **layout** when resized.

http://jsfiddle.net/tylergreen/9v296/

You will still probably want to mess with the layout a bit, but the functionality is there.

Comment: But why does one row contains only 2 images? in case there is a space, why doesn't it add another image to the row?

Comment: Put your `span3` divs, containing the images, into rows of three?

http://jsfiddle.net/tylergreen/9v296/1/ - For clarification, read the 'Nesting Columns' section here: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem

Comment: You didn't understand me. In your first example you didn't wrap each two images with <div class="row"> but still, the browser showed in each row only two images even if I expand the width. Why is that? I am looking for a solution that will put images in the row according to the width of the row.

Comment: Then if you have no preference as to how many images should constitute a row, just take out the wrapping divs altogether. They're entirely unnecessary. http://jsfiddle.net/tylergreen/9v296/2/

Comment: I used DIVs because in addition to the image I would like to add text for each image and DIV would wrap the content for an item.

Comment: Then do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/9v296/3/ - Also I would definitely recommend putting some effort into studying up on your CSS and HTML, and doing some experimentation with your code. This is not particularly advanced stuff.

Comment: Glynne, thanks for pointing out the difference between responsive and fluid ... it helped things gel for me!